# Building Change Sets

Tags: change-set

When I create a change set for a large project and add in page layouts, if pages are changed once added to the outbound change set are those changes picked up during the outbound load. Example... I add a page layout and as my project is finishing, a change is made to that page before the outbound change set is sent, will that update be included? Basically is it getting a time stamped copy of a page layout or just a link to the page layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any changes you make to items included in the changeset will be picked up until the moment you hit "Upload".

After that button is pressed, any changes made will have to be uploaded to the destination org via a new changeset.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.